# Update UITableViewCell with value from UIAlertController action sheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uialertcontroller

Alright,

I searched high and low for a solution to this and tried many different things but still no luck.

Basically, I have a tableViewCell that contains a label. When the user taps the label, an action sheet pops up with some choices. Once the selection is made, I'd like to update that same label that the user tapped to launch the action sheet. Is this possible?

I've posted code below. Using NSLog statements, I'm able to determine that the value of the label is being changed in the completion handler of the action sheet's action, but once that chunk of code executes the value of the label resets to its original value, acting as if a change never occurred in the first place. I've also tried setting up my delegate to return the string value from the action sheet but couldn't find any built in methods to be used with the action sheet like pre-iOS 8. Any help is greatly appreciated.

`Parent.h` file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

Pertinent portion of `Parent.m` file:

```
@interface EPSTableViewController () <MyACPresentationDelegate>

@end

@implementation EPSTableViewController

#pragma mark - Custom delegate methods

-(void)presentActionSheet {
    // Init the roof type action sheet
    UIAlertController *actionSheetRoofType = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Roof Type"
                                                                             message:@"Please select a roof type."
                                                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    [actionSheetRoofType addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Asphalt"
                                                        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                      handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
                                                          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                              NSArray *arrayIndexPaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
                                                              NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [arrayIndexPaths objectAtIndex:9];

                                                              EPSTableViewCell *roofTypeCell =  (EPSTableViewCell *)[self tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellIndexPath];

                                                              NSLog(@"Roof type is: %@", roofTypeCell.labelRoofTypeSelection.text);

                                                              roofTypeCell.labelRoofTypeSelection.text = @"Asphalt";
                                                              [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[cellIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

                                                              NSLog(@"Roof type is now: %@", @"Asphalt");                                                              });
                                                      }]];

    [self presentViewController:actionSheetRoofType animated:YES completion:nil];

    NSLog(@"%@ was selected", selection);
}
```

`Child.h`

```
@protocol MyACPresentationDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)presentActionSheet;

@end

@interface EPSTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *labelRoofType;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *labelRoofTypeSelection;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyACPresentationDelegate> presentationDelegate;

@end
```

`Child.m`

```
-(void)configureCell {
    // Init the roof type label
    self.labelRoofType = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    // Setup the average usage label
    self.labelRoofType.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    self.labelRoofType.text = @"Roof Type:";
    self.labelRoofType.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    self.labelRoofType.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.labelRoofType.hidden = NO;
    self.labelRoofType.numberOfLines = 1;
    self.labelRoofType.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.labelRoofType.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

    // Init the roof type selection label (to be used with action sheet)
    self.labelRoofTypeSelection = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    // Setup the average usage label
    self.labelRoofTypeSelection.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.labelRoofTypeSelection.text = @"Tap for roof type";
    self.labelRoofTypeSelection.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            self.labelRoofTypeSelection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.labelRoofTypeSelection.hidden = NO;
    self.labelRoofTypeSelection.numberOfLines = 1;
    self.labelRoofTypeSelection.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.labelRoofTypeSelection.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

    // Init and setup tap gesture recognizer for the roof type selection label
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tgrRoofTypeSelection = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                               action:@selector(labelRoofTypeSelectionTapped)];
    tgrRoofTypeSelection.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    // Add tap gesture recognizer to label
    [self.labelRoofTypeSelection addGestureRecognizer:tgrRoofTypeSelection];

    // Add views to cell
    [self addSubview:self.labelRoofType];
    [self addSubview:self.labelRoofTypeSelection];

    // Add view constraints
    NSDictionary *views = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[self.labelRoofType, self.labelRoofTypeSelection]
                                                          forKeys:@[@"label", @"selection"]];

    NSLayoutConstraint *labelConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.labelRoofType
                                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                              toItem:self
                                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                          multiplier:1
                                                                            constant:0];

    NSArray *arrayConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[label]-(>=8,<=100)-[selection]"
                                                                            options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                                                            metrics:nil
                                                                              views:views];

    [self addConstraint:labelConstraint];
    [self addConstraints:arrayConstraints];

}

-(void)labelRoofTypeSelectionTapped {
    if ([self.presentationDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(presentActionSheet)]) {
        [self.presentationDelegate presentActionSheet];
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to update your model that you use as the datasource of the `UITableView`. First set the new value for the label in your model, and then call `[myTableView reloadData];`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. After probing around I figured out that the `[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation]` method does call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, which was always redrawing the cell with the standard values. I went ahead and created a BOOL to tell it when to use the standard value and when to use the selected value from the action sheet within the datasource method for the tableView and it worked like a charm. Much appreciated man!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

After probing around I figured out that the `[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation]` method does call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, which was always redrawing the cell with the standard values. I went ahead and created a `BOOL` to tell it when to use the standard value and when to use the selected value from the action sheet within the datasource method for the tableView and it worked like a charm.